# Getting SOAPBody length efficiently

Tags: java, performance, soap, axiom

I want to get the length of a SOAPBody object. My current implementation is

```
String mBody = body.toString();
int len= mBody.length();
```

Using `org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPBody;`

This takes huge time of the my whole operational time as my SOAP body is very large. This way is very inefficient. How can I take this length in efficient t way ?

Comment: its org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPBody

Comment: What do you mean by `length`?  Do you mean the length of the text inside the `SOAPBody` or the serialized length?

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow read the length _before_ you marshall the XML into a `SOAPBody` ?  I fear that once you have a `SOAPBody` object there is no way to get the length without converting to a String or serializing.

Comment: Don't you get a `Content-Length` (http) header along?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically meaningless. There is no such concept as "length" for a SOAP body, or more generally for an XML element. Here is one reason (among many others):

The `Body` element in a SOAP message is in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` (for SOAP 1.1) or `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` (for SOAP 1.2). If you use the `toString` method to serialize the `SOAPBody` instance to a string, Axiom will therefore generate a namespace declaration on the `Body` element, so that the result is well formed with respect to namespaces. However, when the message is sent over the wire, the SOAP body will be the child of an `Envelope` element which is in the same namespace. In that case, the namespace declaration will be generated on the `Envelope` element and not repeated on the `Body` element.

That means that the number of characters effectively taken by the `Body` element depends on the context in which it is serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the message context to get the content-length:

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getInboundContentLength()
```

Comment: I am using org.apache.synapse.MessageContext . There I have mo such method to get the contentLength